# Java's or C#'s Threads are based on User-Space Threads or Kernel-Space Threads?

Tags: c#, java, .net, multithreading, operating-system

Are Java's and C#'s Threads based on User-Space Threads or Kernel-Space Threads?

Comment: Platform- and implementation-specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C#, threads are OS threads, or backed by a thread pool, which is composed of OS threads anyways.  An OS thread uses both user and kernel resources.

Comment: Note that .NET threads are free to be moved to a different OS thread at any time (no idea about Java, though). That's why there's only a managed thread ID.

Answer (score 2):

In Linux, I understand that they are user space threads.

Linux kernel space threads are effectively part of the operating system, and typically run with high privilege so that they can access the address space of any process.  Implementing Java or C# threads on Linux using kernel-space threads is unnecessary, and would be highly dangerous. (This assumes that it is technically possible ... which I don't think is the case.)

Comment: I think the poster is asking whether each Java/.NET thread is its own kernel-visible thread (i.e. Kernel-Space Threads) or if many Java/.NET threads are scheduled by use-space means to use a single kernel-visible thread (i.e. User-Space Threads, or *lightweight threads*).

Comment: @Karmastan - If he did, he used incorrect terminology.  In Linux there really are kernel *space* threads; i.e. threads that run with access to physical devices, etc.